# Endpoint with or without parameter in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I´m using Spring Boot and I have the endpoint below:

```
/dashboards/views/{space}/{id}/{filter}
```

In my context, the filter parameter can exist or can not.

I would like to know if there is some way to represent this context at the endpoint string. I know that in some languages we can do something like this:

```
/dashboards/views/{space}/{id}/[filter]
```

Does exist something similar in Java?

Comment: Typically filter should become an optional query parameter instead of a path parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Spring `@RequestMapping` supports array of path Strings. So, it can be achieved like -

```
@RequestMapping(
        path = {
                "/dashboards/views/{space}/{id}/{filter}", //with filter
                "/dashboards/views/{space}/{id}".  //without filter
        }
)
```

Additionally, mark the filter object as `@Nullable`

```
@PathVariable @Nullable String filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, filter data mapped as query parameter rather path variable. You can use an optional query parameter using `@RequestParam` for this case

```
@GetMapping("/dashboards/views/")
public String getFoos(@RequestParam(required = false) String filter) {
      ...
}
```

And then you can send/skip data

```
/dashboards/views?filter="data"
/dashboards/views
```

A good article about @RequestParam [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)